# ASP.Net Core hosted in docker SQL-Request times out when result is too large

Tags: c#, sql-server, docker, asp.net-core-2.1

I'm having kind of a strange problem:
I have a Web-Api base on ASP.Net Core 2.1 which, in production, lives in a docker container.
Everything works fine as long as the api doesn't receive queries which have a 'larger' result and by large I mean only about 75 results and a result body size of ~45kB. Which should be no big deal.

So far I tracked the issue down to the sql connection:
E.g. if I try to get all CustomerModels the api makes three sql queries:

- first to get the customer entities
- second to get all related projects
- third to get all related places

The first query works perfectly fine. The second times out and the third never gets hit. I already tried to change 2nd and 3rd without any result, still the 2nd  times out. I even tried to replace the 2nd query with a dummy which only returns one row: same problem.
So I build a try-catch around these query to see what causes the problem:

```json
   "ClassName": "System.Data.DataException",
   "Message": "Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.",
   "Data": null,
   "InnerException": {
     "ClassName": "System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException",
     "Message": "Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.",
     "Data": {
       "HelpLink.ProdName": "Microsoft SQL Server",
       "HelpLink.EvtSrc": "MSSQLServer",
       "HelpLink.EvtID": "-2",
       "HelpLink.BaseHelpUrl": "http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink",
       "HelpLink.LinkId": "20476",
       "SqlError 1": "System.Data.SqlClient.SqlError: Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding."
     },
     "InnerException": {
       "ClassName": "System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception",
       "Message": "The wait operation timed out",
       "Data": null,
       "InnerException": null,
       "HelpURL": null,
       "StackTraceString": null,
       "RemoteStackTraceString": null,
       "RemoteStackIndex": 0,
       "ExceptionMethod": null,
       "HResult": -2147467259,
       "Source": null,
       "WatsonBuckets": null,
       "NativeErrorCode": 258
     },
     "HelpURL": null,
     "StackTraceString": "
        at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
        at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
        at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.ReadSniError(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, UInt32 error)
        at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.ReadSniSyncOverAsync()
        at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.TryReadNetworkPacket()
        at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.TryPrepareBuffer()
        at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.TryReadByteArray(Byte[] buff, Int32 offset, Int32 len, Int32& totalRead)
        at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.TryReadString(Int32 length, String& value)
        at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryReadSqlStringValue(SqlBuffer value, Byte type, Int32 length, Encoding encoding, Boolean isPlp, TdsParserStateObject stateObj)
        at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryReadSqlValue(SqlBuffer value, SqlMetaDataPriv md, Int32 length, TdsParserStateObject stateObj)
        at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryReadColumnInternal(Int32 i, Boolean readHeaderOnly)
        at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.GetValueInternal(Int32 i)
        at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.GetValue(Int32 i)
        at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_Item(Int32 i)
        at Deserializefd8a7ec6-63c9-488b-9b4c-84a91ff1d59d(IDataReader )",
     "RemoteStackTraceString": null,
     "RemoteStackIndex": 0,
     "ExceptionMethod": null,
     "HResult": -2146232060,
     "Source": "Core .Net SqlClient Data Provider",
     "WatsonBuckets": null,
     "Errors": null,
     "ClientConnectionId": "57d4bbe9-6c9f-4392-b79f-d72a8cdacd8d"
   },
   "HelpURL": null,
   "StackTraceString": "   at Dapper.SqlMapper.ThrowDataException(Exception ex, Int32 index, IDataReader reader, Object value) in C:\\projects\\dapper\\Dapper\\SqlMapper.cs:line 3609\r\n   at Deserializefd8a7ec6-63c9-488b-9b4c-84a91ff1d59d(IDataReader )\r\n   at Dapper.SqlMapper.QueryAsync[T](IDbConnection cnn, Type effectiveType, CommandDefinition command)\r\n   at FM.Iniquitas.Data.Repositories.ProjektRepositoryAsync.GetByProjectIDs(IEnumerable`1 projectIDs)",
   "RemoteStackTraceString": null,
   "RemoteStackIndex": 0,
   "ExceptionMethod": null,
   "HResult": -2146233087,
   "Source": "Dapper",
   "WatsonBuckets": null
 }
```

So obviously the connection and/or the command times out. So I changed both to 1000 seconds, which doesn't make any difference because the sql queries aren't very complex and shouldn't take more than a few miliseconds.

The sql call itself is in a using-block:

```
 using (var uow = _dataService.StartUnitOfWork())
     {
         var entities = await uow.CustomerRepository.GetAll(); //works fine
         return await BuildModel(entities); //times out
     }
```

The GetAll() part works fine, but in BuildModel I call something like this (again via a repository but for simplification the actual code which is called):

```
var result = await UnitOfWork.Connection.QueryAsync<Projekt>("SELECT * FROM Project WHERE Id IN @ProjectIDs", new { ProjectIDs = projectIDs }, transaction: UnitOfWork.Transaction);
```

With the transaction I tried both cases: each query having its own UnitOfWork and all three queries sharing the same UnitOfWork -> no difference

I tried to track it on the MS-SQL-Server and the there the task gets suspended after a 'ASYNC_NETWORK_IO' wait.

But the real weirdness is: **This problem only appears when the api is hosted inside a docker container.** When I debug it (via Visual Studio) or even host it in production on an IIS-Server (which is not the dev machine) it works perfectly fine. The same api call responds within ~150ms. So I guess this issue is somehow related to the docker container.
Those are the docker-images I'm using:

- Runtime: 2.1.2-aspnetcore-runtime-nanoserver-sac2016
- SDK: 2.1.302-sdk-nanoserver-sac2016

Btw: The Api also uses a Hangfire-Middleware which connects to the same sql-server without any problems. Only time it had a problem was while I called one of those 'larger' queries. In this case Hangfire also threw an sql-timeout exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a network problem. The docker host also hosted the SQL server and somehow a container is able to reach its host but with major losses. Thats the part that made me struggle: It would be understandable if the container couldn't reach its host at all (by default for security concerns), but this 'its possible but only slow' wasn't on my mind.

Fastest workaround is to connect the container to the hosts network. Then it works like a charm.

Btw: If someone has problems with traefik beeing slow working with the docker daemon: Same reason. Connect the traefik-container to the hosts network and it will speed up.

So I guess I will have to do a deeper dive into docker networking to find a routing-solution.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. My first query succeeds but the second query fails. Did you have any luck fixing this issue in bridged network mode?

Comment: For the sql server: I moved it to a container which fixed the network problem.
For traefik: I switched to docker swarm, then published the traefik service ports (80,443) in host mode.
works like a charm now